# getSize() properties not accessible with Angular 2 Go Protractor

Tags: selenium, angular, protractor

I've been using the [Angular2 Go Protractor](https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/angular2-go-protractor) configuration to try to run end to end tests on Angular 2.

When trying to get the size of an element, its properties are not traversable. For example:

```
var myElement = element(by.css('.my-element')).getSize();
```

In the `browser.pause()` debugging console, this will display:

```
{ ceil: {},
  clone: {},
  floor: {},
  height: 52,
  round: {},
  scale: {},
  toString: {},
  width: 612 }
```

But when I try to do `myElementWidth = element(by.css('.my-element')).getSize().width` it will come out as undefined. `myElementWidth = element(by.css('.my-element')).getSize().getWidth()` similarly complains that `getWidth` is not a function. Doing a `console.log` of the object returned by `getSize()` seems to return the original element, not the size object that I'm trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getSize()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getSize) as all of the WebDriver-specific methods *returns a promise*. To get to the actual `size` object, resolve the promise first:

```
element(by.css('.my-element')).getSize().then(function (size) {
    console.log(size);
    console.log(size.width);
});
```

---

But, if you need to make expectations, `expect()` is able to understand promises and resolve them explicitly. In other words, you can write:

```
expect(element(by.css('.my-element')).getSize()).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
    width: 50,
    height: 20
});
```